# compare values in two cells even if the values are not in same order

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have two columns A and B. Value in Cell A1 is "abc, def, ghi" and value in cell B1 is "ghi, abc, def". The cells contain same values . However, not in same order . If A1=B1 is used I get false. How do i get it right .

Comment: Hi, are values in a cell always comma-separated followed by space? If I got it right, for you "ghi, abc, def" = "abc, def, ghi"? and the result comparing A1 and B1 should be True?

Comment: yes. However the value will not always be 3 . Can have 4 values as well

Comment: eg : abc, def, ghi, xyz in A1 and xyz, def, ghi, abc in B1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function SameStuff(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Boolean
    Dim bad As Boolean

    SameStuff = False
    ary1 = Split(Replace(s1, " ", ""), ",")
    ary2 = Split(Replace(s2, " ", ""), ",")
    If UBound(ary1) <> UBound(ary2) Then Exit Function

    For Each a1 In ary1
        bad = True
        For Each a2 In ary2
            If a1 = a2 Then bad = False
        Next a2
        If bad = True Then Exit Function
    Next a1
    SameStuff = True
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

***Note:***

- the *space* character is discarded
- there can be more than three items in each cell.
- TRUE means that the items in **B1** are a *permutation* of the items in **A1**